Prevent npm from running in the background by default
I noticed I was getting random "notifications" within my terminal that npm had an update available (similar but not identical to what's shown in this post which helped me disable that feature).
This creates concern that node/npm/some related service is running in the background, which to my knowledge I have not asked it to do. I don't use node/npm often, certainly I haven't used it since the last time I started my device, so it seems to have started up automatically.
What else, if anything, is node doing in the background? Is there a way to prevent all node background services and have it run only when I explicitly ask?
(I recognise the possibility that disabling this behaviour may vary depending on platform, so for clarification, I'm using Linux)

node or npm dont run "in the background" and dont do in any way something on their own. These a "cli" tools, which need interaction from a user. Never heard or experienced something similar. Please clarify your problem.
